# Вылетает если ничего не ввести в QLineEdit,как устранить?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qlineedit

Суть в том, что если пользователь ничего не в введёт в `QLineEdit` и нажать пуск программа вылетает.

Как сделать так, чтобы программа не вылетала или например, выскакивало сообщение о том, что надо ввести в `QLineEdit`.

Потоки обязательны, `print` в методе `run` сделано специально, чтобы вызвать ошибку.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(452, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 50, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class theThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, s1):
        super(theThread, self).__init__()

        self.s1 = s1

    def run(self):
        print(self.s1 + 2)  # сделанно специально что-бы если не ввёл ничего вызвало ошибку


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)

    def func1(self):
        self.s1 = int(self.lineEdit.text())
        self.thread = theThread(self.s1)
        self.thread.start()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.setWindowTitle("Hello world :-)")
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Добавлю от себя,может кому пригодиться. isalnum() - Вернёт True, если в строке хотя бы один символ и все символы строки являются цифрами и/или буквами, иначе — False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо оперировать с числами,  правильно использовать виджет `QSpinBox`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(452, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

#        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
#        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 113, 20))
#        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget, minimum=0, maximum=9999)   # <---
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 113, 20))
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")        

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 50, 100, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class theThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, s1):
        super(theThread, self).__init__()
        self.s1 = s1

    def run(self):
        rez = "{} + 2 = {}".format( self.s1, self.s1 + 2 )
        print(rez)                                          # ошибок больше  не булет !
        self.mysignal.emit(rez)

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
        self.spinBox.setValue(2)

    def func1(self):
        self.thread = theThread(self.spinBox.value())
        self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.rezult)
        self.thread.start()

    def rezult(self, value):
        self.label.setText(value)
        self.label.adjustSize()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.setWindowTitle("Hello world :-)")
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(452, 290)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 200, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 100, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 50, 100, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class theThread(QtCore.QThread):
    mysignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, s1):
        super(theThread, self).__init__()
        self.s1 = int(s1)

    def run(self):
        rez = "{} + 2 = {}".format( self.s1, self.s1 + 2 )
        print(rez)                                          # ошибок больше  не булет !
        self.mysignal.emit(rez)

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)
#        self.spinBox.setValue(2)


    def func1(self):
        if self.lineEdit.text().isnumeric():                    # Для положительных целых чисел
            self.thread = theThread(self.lineEdit.text())
            self.thread.mysignal.connect(self.rezult)
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Information',
                'Для арифметических вычислений необходимо ввести цисло!')

    def rezult(self, value):
        self.label.setText(value)
        self.label.adjustSize()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.setWindowTitle("Hello world :-)")
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С числами оперировать не нужно,это пример.

Comment: @Leon я добавил второй пример.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте простейшую проверку в методе `func1`:

```
if(self.lineEdit.text() == "")
    // Здесь выводится текст "нужно заполнить QLineEdit"
```